# Convert UTC offset date to different time zone

Tags: java, timezone-offset

I would like to convert date with its UTC offset to the different timezone.

Suppose that I get `2021-06-14 06:56:00` (this is local date time) with UTC offset `+3` hours and I need to convert this local date time to `LosAngeles` timezone (UTC -8 hours). In order to implement this, I wrote the following snippet:

```
    public static LocalDateTime toPstTimeZone(LocalDateTime localDateTime, int utcOffset) {
        final var pstUtcOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(-8);
        return localDateTime
                .atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(utcOffset))
                .withOffsetSameInstant(pstUtcOffset)
                .toLocalDateTime();
    }
```

need to check if this is valid approach to do.

Comment: If you want to do operations with timezones using LocalDateTime which explicitly does not support any timezone data isn't really a good idea. Why not use ZonedDateTime instead? Thats what the class is for after all.

Comment: Ok, suppose that I will use the `ZonedDateTime`, how it could help me to convert to the different UTC offset (say, from UTC +3 to UTC -8, LA timezone)?

Comment: Don't use `ZoneOffset.ofHours(-8)`.  Use `ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")`.  The difference is that the latter will properly handle daylight saving time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct. However, I would suggest if possible to work to begin with, with ZonedDateTime or OffsetDateTime. in this case switching between timezones is much easier. For ZonedDateTime switching to different time zone is just one method: [public ZonedDateTime withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId zone)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-)